# How can I change style of element with jQuery function and media query when resize event working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive web site, and I have some problems at resize.
I using media query at ww<1280, ww<1024, ww<640, then controll elements with Jquery Functions.

when document loaded, media query and functions are worked well.
but, when I try some jquery functions then resize window, there are so many problems.

one of function I wrote is,

```
var menuOpen = function() {
  var ctryBtn = $(".countryMenu input[type=button]");
  var ctryMenu = $(".countryMenu");
  var subGnb = $("#subGnb");
  var gnbBtn = $("#header button.mobileGnbBtn");
  var myGnb = $("#gnb");
  var schBtn = $(".mobileFindBtn");
  var schMenu = $(".utilMenu");
  var gnbDown = function () {
    $("#gnb ul").append("<li class='mobileSiteMap'><a href='siteMap.html'>Site Map</a></li>");
    myGnb.slideDown(500,function () {
      $(".mobileGnbBtn").css({
        "width":"37px",
        "height":"37px",
        "background-image":"url(image/common/btn-close-mobile.png)",
        "background-size":"cover"
      });
    });
  };
  var gnbUp = function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 623) {
      myGnb.slideUp(500, function () {
        $(".mobileSiteMap").remove();
        $(".mobileGnbBtn").css({
          "width":"43px",
          "height":"37px",
          "background-image":"url(image/common/btn-menu-mobile.png)"
        });
      });
    } else {
      $(".mobileSiteMap").remove();
      return false;
    }
  };
  ctryBtn.on("click", function () {
    if(isSubGNB === false){
      subGnb.slideDown(500);
      isSubGNB = true;
    } else {
      subGnb.slideUp(500);
      isSubGNB = false;
    }
  });

  gnbBtn.on("click", function () {
    if(isGNB === false){
      if(isSubGNB === true || isSearch === true){
        subGnb.slideUp(500);
        isSubGNB = false;
        schMenu.slideUp(500);
        isSearch = false;
        ctryMenu.fadeIn(300);
      }
      gnbDown();
      isGNB = true;
    } else {
      gnbUp();
      isGNB = false;
    }
  });
  schBtn.on("click", function () {
    if (isSearch === false) {
      if (isGNB === true || isSubGNB === true ) {
        gnbUp();
        isGNB = false;
        subGnb.slideUp(500);
        isSubGNB = false;
      }
      ctryMenu.fadeOut(100);
      schMenu.slideDown(300);
      isSearch = true;
    } else {
      schMenu.slideUp(100);
      isSearch = false;
      ctryMenu.fadeIn(300);
    }
  });
};
```

`#gnb` is absolute positioned at ww<640, invisible(display:none), and different children elements setting with another ww sizes.
`#gnb` is relative positioned at upper 640px ww.

Then I wrote resize event like:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
  var gnbPC = function () {
    $("#gnb").css({
      "width":"410px",
      "height":"76px",
      "letter-spacing":"-0.04em",
      "margin-left":"26.866%"
    });
  };
  var toggleMobile = function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 623 ) {
      $("#subGnb").css({"display":"none"});
    } else {
      gnbPC();
      $("#subGnb").css({"display":"none"});
    }
  };
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(toggleMobile, delta);
});
```

I set var delta = null; var timer = null;

Under 640px ww, when I click button, `#gnb` slideDown, and slideUp well.
when `#gnb` slideUp, then I try resize to upper 640px,
there is no `#gnb` because it had invisibled when slideUp() finished.

So I try to give it CSS set(default value of CSS ww>640),
but it is written inline, then mediaQuery didn't work.

I want some solution, when I trying resize window,
function work then reload for default setting for ww size.
Or, solve this resizing problems.

I want reset when resize,
if `#gnb` opened, then I try resize, I want it closed then change to default setting for ww size.